# Fail to show CSS bg in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Working on the index page of my application and for some reason the bg-image I added doesn't render. However all the other image files I call does (however not called in the CSS, like this one is)

It shows up perfectly in development, but not in production.

I get the following error in my heroku logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/ctabackground.png"):
```

My CSS:

```
#cta {
 text-align:center;
 height:600px;
 width:100%;
 background:url('ctabackground.png') no-repeat $light-green;
 h1, h2 {
 color:#fff;
}
 h2 {
  letter-spacing:2px;
  font-weight:300;
 }
}
```

the file lies in assets/images/ as ctabackground.png

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use rails asset_path for proper url. Try:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'ctabackground.png' %>) no-repeat $light-green;
```

**Update:**

Since you are using sass you can use rails `image-url` helper

```
background-image: image-url('ctabackground.png') no-repeat $light-green;
```

Comment: yeah, thought along those lines as-well only problem is that it's in my .css.scss file thus it doesn't run rails code.

Comment: @user2755537 oh but in production rails precompile all your assets and an MD5 is generated from the contents so you won't have access to paths like `assets/images/image.png` that's why we use asset_path to make proper urls. If you don't want to make it an erb file then i would recommend using an image_tag instead of using your image as background

Comment: didn't know that! then I learned something new :) still haven't been able to fix the current issue though.

Comment: @user2755537 how are you using it now? and checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Comment: When I link to images from my hmtl.erb file I just do <%= image_tag 'path' %>

Comment: yes that works. However this is from the assets/stylesheet/static_pages.css.scss that I am having issues with now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56843/discussion-between-mandeep-and-user2755537).